# Publish to Current user's wall using FBJS in FBML application

Tags: facebook, fbml, fbjs

I need to publish some message to the current user's wall using FBJS in FBML application.
When I use

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({appId: 'MY_APP_ID', status: true, cookie: true, xfbml: false});
};
```

i am getting an error :- FB is not defined.
and
window is not defined.
For publishing i am using this code

```
function graphStreamPublish(){
           var body = document.getElementById("txtTextToPublish").value;
            FB.api('/me/feed', 'post', { message: body }, function(response) {
                if (!response || response.error) {
                    // alert('Error occured');
                } else {
                    // alert('Post ID: ' + response.id);
                }
           });
     }
```

(I cannot use alert in facebook..)

Thanks in advance..

Comment: Use `console.log` instead of alert.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using FBML, you should be using FBJS instead of the Facebook Connect API.

```
var body = document.getElementById('txtTextToPublish').getValue();
Facebook.streamPublish(body);
```

Note the getValue() call instead of .value due to use of FBJS.